# Search in Array field in Postgres

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, postgresql-9.5

I have the following table structure here `countries` column is of array type.

```
 id | name  |             countries             
----+-------+-----------------------------------
  1 | Asia  | {india,china,pakistan,bangladesh}
  2 | World | {india,pakistan,srilanka}
```

To find all rows of `china or sriLanka`
I use below query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM country_list 
WHERE 'china' = ANY(country_list.countries) 
   OR 'srilanka' = ANY(country_list.countries);
```

Can we have any better way to do this  just like `In` operator?

Maybe something like, `SELECT * FROM country_list WHERE name in ('Asia','World');`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`&&` overlaps operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-array.html):

```
select *
from country_list
where countries && array['china','srilanka'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This Query Like.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE name @> ARRAY['s']::varchar[]
```